# Android In-app-billing for digital content

Tags: android

I am developing an application in which user can buy a song and song can play only within the application. We are planning to use deduct amount from user's balance for payment. But according to Android payment guideline(https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html#payments) required in-app-billing as payment option if content is consumed within the application.
Please suggest can we use user's balance for payment or Google reject this approach.

Answer (score 0):

If content used only within the app you need use in-app-billing only. Another billing services is prohibited. You will banned if you use another billing.

> Developers offering additional content, services or functionality within another category of app downloaded from Google Play must use Google Play's in-app billing service as the method of payment.

Purchased songs are virtual goods and its used within application, so you must Google Play's in-app billing service as the method of payment.